# Dumping Firebird DB tables with ar_firebird_adapter into Rails schema.rb and not all tables are dumping correctly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, schema, firebird

First off, I am using `ar_firebird_adapter` which is a nifty adapter that allows Rails and FB to integrate fairly seamlessly (the only adapter that is compatible with Rails 6).  The problem that I am having is once I am connected to my Firebird DB and I run `rake db:schema:dump`, some of the tables come in like so:

```
# Could not dump table "country" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'VARCHAR' for column 'currency'

# Could not dump table "customer" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'VARCHAR' for column 'customer'

# Could not dump table "department" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'VARCHAR' for column 'department'

# Could not dump table "employee" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'VARCHAR' for column 'phone_ext'

  create_table "employee_project", primary_key: ["proj_id", "emp_no"], force: :cascade do |t|
    t.boolean "emp_no", null: false
    t.boolean "proj_id", null: false
    t.index ["emp_no", "proj_id"], name: "rdb$primary14", unique: true
    t.index ["emp_no"], name: "rdb$foreign15"
    t.index ["proj_id"], name: "rdb$foreign16"
  end

# Could not dump table "job" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'VARCHAR' for column 'job_title'

# Could not dump table "proj_dept_budget" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'INTEGER' for column 'fiscal_year'

# Could not dump table "project" because of following StandardError
#   Unknown type 'VARCHAR' for column 'proj_name'
```

As you can see, any DB that is clear and void of "unknown" types comes across fine but the above types get listed as a `StandardError` (including `TIMESTAMP`)

Now, I read that I need to use `rake db:structure:load` after putting this into my `application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.schema_format = :sql
```

Problem is, when I use `rake db:structure:load`, this is the error I get:

```
rake aborted!
ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseNotSupported: Rake tasks not supported by 'ar_firebird' adapter

Tasks: TOP => db:structure:dump
```

Does this mean the adapter does not utilize that rake command and if so, how do I fix it?  This is a huge hurdle I need to get over!  I will be elated if someone can help me.

Comment: Question was also posted to: https://github.com/rails-firebird/ar_firebird_adapter/issues/20

Comment: It looks like you're using the example employee database included in Firebird. Be aware that this example database uses array columns, which a lot of tools and drivers for Firebird do not support (though that doesn't seem to be the issue here).

Comment: Thanks for linking that Mark.  Yes sir, you are correct about this being the example database.  I wanted to make sure I could successfully dump into rails before I went to our live DB.  Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have no experience with rails, so I can't be of help there.

Comment: We can suggest you what `Varchar` datatype is, what properties it has, how to interprete the output of FB API or of "system tables" - but you would need to code it into Ruby library you use, or faind some interested Rubbist who would...

Comment: I wanted to avoid that but if I have to figure it out, I will.  I'll work my way into whatever solution is necessary.  In the meantime, I can only hope the gem maintainers respond to my issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So.. the answer was fairly simple; try another adapter made by the same group of guys!

I ended up using `firebird_adapter` and `db:schema:dump` worked like a charm.

I did have to account for a few unknown data types within the gem, but other than that, it was all good.

Thanks for those that looked/commented.

Comment: unfortunately, firebird_adapter doesn't work with Rails 6...

Comment: Yeah, unfortunately, you are right.  I settled on Rails 5.1, which is plenty fine for my use-case.